# Configure JBoss management interface login to use SSO

Tags: jboss7.x, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have a brand new JBOSS 7 EAP server running. On that server I want to configure the Management Interface to use a remote SSO server for authentication. In our case this SSO server is a WSO2 Identity Server using SAML. Got to the point where applications that got deployed can use this SSO mechanism, but did not find any documentation about the management console itself. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Marco